# Exponent of complex numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, complex-numbers

Given two integers, which may be negative, zero, or positive, \$a\$ and \$b\$ (taken in any reasonable format, **including inputting a plain complex number**), convert it to \$a + bi\$ where \$i\$ is the imaginary number (square root of negative one). Then, raise it to the power of a third (positive integer) input variable, \$c\$ as to \$(a + bi)^c\$. You should then end up with something like \$d + ei\$. You must then output, or return, \$d\$ and \$e\$ in any reasonable format (**including outputting a plain complex number**).

Input and output may be taken or outputted in any order.

Examples:

```
5, 2, 2 -> 21, 20
1, 4, 2 -> -15, 8
-5, 0, 1 -> -5, 0
```

Comment: If we use de Moivre's formula, is floating point imprecison allowed?

Comment: @Giuseppe Yes, that's okay.

Comment: FWIW I think the change to the rules (allowing a fully flexible I/O) made a fairly interesting challenge pretty dull.

Comment: @JonathanAllan at least for languages with native complex number support -- which are quite many :(

Comment: @JonathanAllan I can't please everyone :(

Comment: @Okx I know, just pointing out to others that I (and it seems from upvotes, others) prefered your original idea :)

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
ReIm[(#+#2I)^#3]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyjVMzdaQ1lb2chTM07ZOFbtf0BRZl6JgkN6tKmOghEQxXLBRQx1FExQRXSBigx0FAxj/wMA)

-8 bytes from alephalpha

but........
rules have changed......
so

## Mathematica, 5 bytes

```
Power
```

Comment: `{Re@#,Im@#}&` -> `ReIm`

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyjVMzdaQ1lb2chTM07ZOFbtf0BRZl6JgkN6tKmOghEQxXLBRQx1FExQRXSBigx0FAxj/wMA). You can simply remove `@#&`.

Comment: haha, yes, my mistake

Comment: You can now do `#^#2&` or just `Power`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3 bytes

```python
pow
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzvyC//H9afpFCok6STrJCZp5CtKmOghEQxepEG@oomEBYukBBAx0Fw1grLgWFgqLMvBKNNI1E7SQtwyydZE3N/wA)

Input and output as complex numbers.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,c):n=(a+b*1j)**c;return n.real,n.imag
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1EnSSdZ0yrPViNRO0nLMEtTSyvZuii1pLQoTyFPryg1MUcnTy8zNzH9f1p@kQJYtUJmnkK0qY6CERDF6kQb6iiYQFi6QEEDHQXDWCsuBYWCosy8Eg2YBZr/AQ)

Input and output as integers

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> 60 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Leonhard*

```python
a,b,c=input();d=1;e=0
exec'd,e=a*d-b*e,a*e+b*d;'*c
print d,e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPQ/USdJJ9k2M6@gtERD0zrF1tA61daAK7UiNVk9RSfVNlErRTdJK1UnUStVO0krxVpdK5mroCgzr0QBKPsfaABYqQLIOC3j/9GmOgpGQBTLFW2oo2ACYekCBQ10FAxjAQ)

does not use complex number type

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
a=>b=>g=c=>c?([x,y]=g(c-1),[x*a-b*y,a*y+b*x]):"10"
```

- Takes input in currying form: `f(a)(b)(c)`
- Returns the result as an array: `[d, e]`

**Explanation**

```
a=>b=>g=c=>               // Input in currying syntax
    c?(                   // If `c` != 0:
        [x,y]=g(c-1),     //     Set [x, y] to the result of f(a)(b)(c-1)
        [x*a-b*y,a*y+b*x] //     Return (a + bi) * (x + yi)
    ):                    // Else: (when c = 0)
        "10"              //     Return [1, 0] (to end the recursion)
```

```js
f=a=>b=>g=c=>c?([x,y]=g(c-1),[x*a-b*y,a*y+b*x]):"10"
```

```html
<div oninput="o.innerText=f(a.value)(b.value)(c.value)"><input id=a type=number value=0><input id=b type=number value=0><input id=c type=number value=1 min=1><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r////GqbaRlma/40A)

Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for alerting me of rule updates (-6 as a result).
Thanks to [someone](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/someone) for alerting me of rule updates (-2 as a result).

First argument: `(a+bj)`
Second argument: `c`
Returns: `(d+ej)`

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//xLHDpi4qwrXhuJ4sxIr///9bMiwgNV3/Mg)

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4biFxLEqwrXhuJ4sxIr///9bMiw1Xf8y)

Comment: In fact Jonathan's 3 byter would suffice; `ḅı*`, as the rules have changed and you are now allowed to output a plain complex number.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder was sleeping when that happened

Comment: It seems like a * onebyter is ok now as you can take input as a complex

Comment: [Works in Dyalog APL too.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSt//9Ns4wU0hSMAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 36 bytes

```
f(a,b,c)=divrem((a+b*x)^c%(x^2+1),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P00jUSdJJ1nTNiWzrCg1V0MjUTtJq0IzLllVoyLOSNtQU6dC839BUWZeiUaahqmOghEQaWpywUQMdRRMUEV0gYoMdBQMNTX/AwA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 36 bytes

```
f(a,b,c)=[real(d=(a+b*I)^c),imag(d)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P00jUSdJJ1nTNrooNTFHI8VWI1E7SctTMy5ZUyczNzFdI0Uz9n9BUWZeiUaahqmOghEQaWpywUQMdRRMUEV0gYoMdBQMNTX/AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

```
ⁿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9R4/7//424NIy0TbM0AQ)

Note that the rules have changed and complex numbers are valid I/O types (unfortunately this turns the post into a "perform this exponentiation" challenge). Original answer below.

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 3 bytes

```
Çⁿ╫
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9w@6PG/Y@mrv7/34jLhMsQAA)

Returns the values separated by a newline. Takes the inputs in reverse order and returns the results in reverse order (See the tio link).

```
Çⁿ╫  - Full program. Reversed inputs.

Ç    - Return a+bi.
 ⁿ   - Exponentiation.
  ╫  - Pushes the real and imaginary parts of a.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 3 bytes

This is becoming boring. If input and output is allowed as a complex number, there is a builtin for a power function.

```r
`^`
```

For example:

```r
> (5+2i)^2
[1] 21+20i
> (1+4i)^2
[1] -15+8i
> (-5+0i)^1
[1] -5+0i
```

or

```r
> `^`(5+2i,2)
[1] 21+20i
> `^`(1+4i,2)
[1] -15+8i
> `^`(-5+0i,1)
[1] -5+0i
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>5</s> <s>12</s> <s>5</s> 2 bytes

```
^E
```

Takes in `c` first, followed by `a+bj`.

<s>7 bytes of boilerplate because apparently output as an imaginary number is disallowed.</s>  It's been re-allowed! Hurrah!  And with taking in a complex number being a reasonable input, we can cut out an additional 3 bytes!

Previous solutions:

```
^.jEE
```

When complex numbers were not reasonable inputs.

```
m,edsd]^.jEE
```

When complex numbers were not reasonable outputs.

[Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%5EE&input=2%0A5%0A2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A5%2B2j%0A%0A2%0A1%2B4j%0A%0A1%0A-5%2B0j%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/9/9/Iy4NU22jLE0A)

Input: `c\n(a+bj)`
Output: `(d+ej)`

Comment: Same tip as Neil, [`'jì+³m`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fPevwGu1Dm3P//zfiMuUyAgA) is a different way to calculate the number.

Comment: @Adnan at least for me it does matter indeed :p

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>62</s> 38 bytes

```cs
a=>c=>System.Numerics.Complex.Pow(a,c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xCoMwFEX3fEXolKDNIHSyugiFQltKLXRO04c8iIkksVbEb7cdHFyEbvfCOZer/FZZB1PTPjUqqrT0nhYD8UGGXy97H6AWh9ao/ZwvbQ0OlReFrRsNn3jJoAnxCpfnTTbJLFdZvkKIq@2YjBWfUjL/mW@8Lb7oWaJhnAyzXVjjrQbxcBjghAZYwwx0dGWc7eKEc5ZwcQOpxd2WwaGpGI82dBP9qR5rWaGRrl/4PCUjGacv)

Comment: You should include the `.Real` and .Imaginary` in your answer.. According to the rule "_You must then output, or return, `d` and `e` in any reasonable format (not including outputting a plain complex number)_" you're not allowed to just output the Complex number.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
‚UTSsFXâP`(‚RŠ‚+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOs0JDgYreIw4sCEjSAvKCjC4Ck9v//JlyGXEYA) Takes three separate inputs in the order `b, a, c` and outputs an array `[d, e]`. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Datboi. Saved 1 byte thanks to @Adnan. Explanation:

```
‚                   Join a and b into a pair
 U                  Store in variable X
  T                 Push 10 to the stack
   S                Split into the pair [d, e] = [1, 0]
    s               Swap with c
     F              Repeat the rest of the program c times
      X             Get [a, b]
       â            Cartesian product with [d, e]
        P           Multiply each pair together [da, db, ea, eb]
         `          Push each product as a separate stack entry
          (         Negate eb
           ‚        Join with ea into a pair [ea, -eb]
            R       Reverse the pair [-eb, ea]
             Š      Push under da and db
              ‚     Join them into a pair [da, db]
               +    Add the two pairs [da-eb, db+ea]
```

Comment: *Input and output may be taken or outputted in any order.* - That means that you can take the first two inputs in reverse order.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters or not, but calculating the number can also be done with [`'jì+³m`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fPevwGu1Dm3P//zfhMuQyAgA).

Comment: You can replace `1 0‚` with `TS` for -2 bytes :)

Comment: And `P` automatically vectorizes, so you don't need the `€`.

Comment: @Adnan so what's "total product" supposed to mean then?

Comment: Yes, docs are crap, but I'm planning on changing this when I have some free time (with examples etc.).

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 8 bytes

Takes the complex number and the exponent as input, and stores output in `Ans` as a complex number.  Drastic drop in bytes due to loosened restrictions on input/output.

```
Prompt C,E
C^E
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `imag({iAns,Ans` in the last line (by `i` I mean the complex number *i*).

Comment: And I guess then one more byte by just combining the two lines into `imag({i,1}(A+Bi)^C`.

Comment: Rules have changed, now you can take input and return complex numbers, if that is of any help.

Answer (score 2):

## J, <sub><s>10</s></sub>, <sub><s>7</s></sub>, 1 byte<s>s</s>

```
^
```

Takes `c` as the right argument and the complex number `ajb` (how you represent `a + bi` in J) as the left argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL44rNTkjX8E0y0ghTcEIwjHMMkFw4k2zDIA8w///AQ)

### Other Solutions

#### 7 bytes

Takes the complex number input as a list.

```
^~j./@]
```

#### 10 bytes

This outputted the `a + bi` in the list `a b`.

```
+.@^~j./@]
```

I wanted to try something cute like `^~&.(j./)` but the inverse of `j./` is obviously not defined. Actually, `^~&.(+.inv)` works and you can make that `^&.(+.inv)` which is also 10 bytes if you reverse the order in which you take the args.

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) subroutine, <strike>199</strike> <strike>187</strike> 185 bytes

```
A2 03 B5 FB 95 26 CA 10 F9 88 D0 01 60 A5 26 85 61 A5 27 85 62 A5 FB 85 63 A5
FC 85 64 A9 20 85 6F D0 36 18 A5 6D 65 65 85 28 A5 6E 65 66 85 29 A5 4B 85 26
A5 4C 85 27 50 CF 38 A5 6D E5 65 85 4B A5 6E E5 66 85 4C A5 28 85 61 A5 29 85
62 A5 FB 85 63 A5 FC 85 64 06 6F A9 00 85 65 85 66 A2 10 46 62 66 61 90 0D A5
63 18 65 65 85 65 A5 64 65 66 85 66 06 63 26 64 CA 10 E6 A9 FF 24 6F 70 B9 30
02 F0 9E A5 65 85 6D A5 66 85 6E 24 6F 30 14 A5 28 85 61 A5 29 85 62 A5 FD 85
63 A5 FE 85 64 06 6F D0 B4 A5 26 85 61 A5 27 85 62 A5 FD 85 63 A5 FE 85 64 06
6F B0 A0
```

- *-12 bytes with improved "spaghetti" structure*
- *-2 bytes changing the register to pass the exponent, so we can make use of zeropage addressing mode in the initial copy loop*

This is position-independent code, just put it somewhere in RAM and call it with a `jsr` instruction.

The routine takes the (complex) base as two 16bit signed integers (2's complement, little-endian) in `$fb/$fc` (real) and `$fd/$fe` (imaginary), and the exponent as an unsigned 8bit integer in the `Y` register.

The result is returned in `$26/$27` (real) and `$28/$29` (imaginary).

---

#### Explanation

This is still an interesting challenge on the 6502 CPU as there are no instructions for even multiplying. The approach is straight forward, implementing a complex multiplication and executing it as often as required by the exponent. Golfing is done by avoiding subroutines, instead creating kind of a "branch spaghetti", so the code for doing a simple 16bit multiplication that's needed multiple times is reused with the lowest possible overhead. Here's the commented disassembly:

```
 .cexp:
A2 03       LDX #$03            ; copy argument ...
 .copyloop:
B5 FB       LDA $FB,X
95 26       STA $26,X
CA          DEX
10 F9       BPL .copyloop       ; ... to result
 .exploop:
88          DEY                 ; decrement exponent
D0 01       BNE .mult           ; zero reached -> done
60          RTS
 .mult:                         ; multiply (complex) result by argument
A5 26       LDA $26             ; prepare to multiply real components
85 61       STA $61             ; (a*c)
A5 27       LDA $27
85 62       STA $62
A5 FB       LDA $FB
85 63       STA $63
A5 FC       LDA $FC
85 64       STA $64
A9 20       LDA #$20            ; marker for where to continue
85 6F       STA $6F
D0 36       BNE .mult16         ; branch to 16bit multiplication
 .mult5:
18          CLC                 ; calculate sum (a*d) + (b*c)
A5 6D       LDA $6D
65 65       ADC $65
85 28       STA $28             ; and store to imaginary component of result
A5 6E       LDA $6E
65 66       ADC $66
85 29       STA $29
A5 4B       LDA $4B             ; load temporary result (a*c) - (b*d)
85 26       STA $26             ; and store to real component of result
A5 4C       LDA $4C
85 27       STA $27
50 CF       BVC .exploop        ; next exponentiation step
 .mult3:
38          SEC                 ; calculate difference (a*c) - (b*d)
A5 6D       LDA $6D
E5 65       SBC $65
85 4B       STA $4B             ; and store to temporary location
A5 6E       LDA $6E
E5 66       SBC $66
85 4C       STA $4C
A5 28       LDA $28             ; prepare to multiply real component of result
85 61       STA $61             ; with imaginary component of argument
A5 29       LDA $29             ; (a*d)
85 62       STA $62
A5 FB       LDA $FB
85 63       STA $63
A5 FC       LDA $FC
85 64       STA $64
06 6F       ASL $6F             ; advance "continue marker"
 .mult16:
A9 00       LDA #$00            ; initialize 16bit multiplication
85 65       STA $65             ; result with 0
85 66       STA $66
A2 10       LDX #$10            ; bit counter (16)
 .m16_loop:
46 62       LSR $62             ; shift arg1 right
66 61       ROR $61
90 0D       BCC .m16_noadd      ; no carry -> nothing to add
A5 63       LDA $63             ; add arg2 ...
18          CLC
65 65       ADC $65
85 65       STA $65
A5 64       LDA $64
65 66       ADC $66
85 66       STA $66             ; ... to result
 .m16_noadd:
06 63       ASL $63             ; shift arg2 left
26 64       ROL $64
CA          DEX                 ; decrement number of bits to go
10 E6       BPL .m16_loop
A9 FF       LDA #$FF            ; check marker for where to continue
24 6F       BIT $6F
70 B9       BVS .mult3
30 02       BMI .saveres        ; have to save result to temp in 2 cases
F0 9E       BEQ .mult5
 .saveres:
A5 65       LDA $65             ; save result to temporary
85 6D       STA $6D
A5 66       LDA $66
85 6E       STA $6E
24 6F       BIT $6F             ; check "continue marker" again
30 14       BMI .mult4
 .mult2:
A5 28       LDA $28             ; prepare to multiply imaginary components
85 61       STA $61             ; (b*d)
A5 29       LDA $29
85 62       STA $62
A5 FD       LDA $FD
85 63       STA $63
A5 FE       LDA $FE
85 64       STA $64
06 6F       ASL $6F             ; advance "continue marker"
D0 B4       BNE .mult16         ; branch to 16bit multiplication
 .mult4:
A5 26       LDA $26             ; prepare to multiply imaginary component of
85 61       STA $61             ; result with real component of argument
A5 27       LDA $27             ; (b*c)
85 62       STA $62
A5 FD       LDA $FD
85 63       STA $63
A5 FE       LDA $FE
85 64       STA $64
06 6F       ASL $6F             ; advance "continue marker"
B0 A0       BCS .mult16         ; branch to 16bit multiplication
```

---

#### Example program using it (C64, assembly source in [ca65](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html)-syntax):

```
.import cexp

CEXP_A          = $fb
CEXP_AL         = $fb
CEXP_AH         = $fc
CEXP_B          = $fd
CEXP_BL         = $fd
CEXP_BH         = $fe

CEXP_RA         = $26
CEXP_RAL        = $26
CEXP_RAH        = $27
CEXP_RB         = $28
CEXP_RBL        = $28
CEXP_RBH        = $29

.segment "LDADDR"
                .word   $c000

.segment "MAIN"
                jsr     $aefd           ; consume comma
                jsr     $ad8a           ; evaluate number
                jsr     $b1aa           ; convert to 16bit int
                sty     CEXP_AL         ; store as first argument
                sta     CEXP_AH
                jsr     $aefd           ; ...
                jsr     $ad8a
                jsr     $b1aa
                sty     CEXP_BL         ; store as second argument
                sta     CEXP_BH
                jsr     $b79b           ; read 8bit unsigned into X
                txa                     ; and transfer
                tay                     ; to Y

                jsr     cexp            ; call our function

                lda     CEXP_RAH        ; read result (real part)
                ldy     CEXP_RAL
                jsr     numout          ; output
                ldx     CEXP_RBH        ; read result (imaginary part)
                bmi     noplus
                lda     #'+'            ; output a `+` if it's not negative
                jsr     $ffd2
noplus:         txa
                ldy     CEXP_RBL
                jsr     numout          ; output (imaginary part)
                lda     #'i'
                jsr     $ffd2           ; output `i`
                lda     #$0d            ; and newline
                jmp     $ffd2

numout:
                jsr     $b391           ; convert to floating point
                jsr     $bddd           ; format floating point as string
                ldy     #$01
numout_loop:    lda     $ff,y           ; output loop
                bne     numout_print    ; until 0 terminator found
                rts
numout_print:   cmp     #' '            ; skip space characters in output
                beq     numout_next
                jsr     $ffd2
numout_next:    iny
                bne     numout_loop
```

---

### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22cexp.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAg/a4giq0gqrGE+4X8IP2uIIqtIKqxhP2F/iCbt4qoIFrApSekJiBCwKYpMAWpKyDS/4qkKCBCwKlJINL/qQ1M0v8gkbMg3b2gAbn/ANABYMkg8AMg0v/I0PCiA7X7lSbKEPmI0AFgpSaFYaUnhWKl+4VjpfyFZKkghW/QNhilbWVlhSilbmVmhSmlS4UmpUyFJ1DPOKVt5WWFS6Vu5WaFTKUohWGlKYVipfuFY6X8hWQGb6kAhWWFZqIQRmJmYZANpWMYZWWFZaVkZWaFZgZjJmTKEOap/yRvcLkwAvCepWWFbaVmhW4kbzAUpSiFYaUphWKl/YVjpf6FZAZv0LSlJoVhpSeFYqX9hWOl/oVkBm+woA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22cexp.prg%22%7D%7D)

**Usage:** `sys49152,[a],[b],[c]`, e.g. `sys49152,5,2,2` (Output: `21+20i`)

Answer (score 1):

## Casio-Basic, 6 bytes

```
a^b
```

Change to the rules to allow input and output as complex numbers made this significantly shorter.

3 bytes for the function, +3 to enter `a,b` in the parameters box.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 1 byte

```
^
```

Inputs are `a+jb`, `c`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P@7/f1NtoywuIwA)

### Old version: non-complex input and output, 8 bytes

```
J*+i^&Zj
```

Input order is `b`,`a`, `c`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30tLOzNOLSrr/38jLlMuIwA)

#### Explanation

```
J           Push imaginary unit
 *          Multiply by implicit input b
  +         Add implicit input a
   i        Take input c
    ^       Power
     &Zj    Push real and imaginary parts. Implicitly display
```

Comment: *Multiply by implicit input **b*** - *Add implicit input **b***. Did you mean **a** in either of those?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, thanks. Corrected

Comment: You can take input in the form of a complex number now, and output in the form of a complex number.  You can probably cut out a lot of boilerplate from this answer because of that.

Comment: @StevenHewitt Thanks! Edited now

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

```apl
⎕*⍨⊣+¯11○⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBKYKGo/6pmo96l3xqGux9qH1hoaPpnc/6lqkqWDEZcTFZYhT2gQkfWg9bv0GXIYA)

`a` is left argument, `b` is right argument, and `c` via input prompt.

Returns a complex number in the format `dJe`.

Comment: Rules have changed, now you can take input and return complex numbers, if that's of any help.

Comment: Now, you can input and output complex numbers directly (according to rules). So the answer is simply the `*` function (or, taking input from stdin and outputting to stdout, we have: `⎕*⎕`).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

```c
#define f(a,b,c)cpow((a)+1i*(b),c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hctBCsIwEEDRvacIlcKMTsAUu/IqbtIxEwJJLK3gQry6MYKibnT5PzzWnrmU5cFJyE4JWBqIkcfjGcDi2oQVDFhPCfmkkg0Z8LIYp1oCqmlFtbLPDSmenI0g0FNHHVYRkvXvVrj7pQxtv9Sz/yjd04bMB3uNh7uWG0u0fi46pjs)

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 6 bytes

```
@power
```

Anonymous function that inputs two numbers and outputs their power.

[**Try it online**!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en99@hIL88teh/moaptlGWjpEmV5qGobYJlKVrqm2QpWOo@R8A)

### Old version: non-complex input and output, 30 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b,c)real((a+j*b)^c./[1 j])
```

Anonymous function that inputs three numbers and outputs an array of two numbers.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSSdZsyg1MUdDI1E7SytJMy5ZTz/aUCErVvN/moapjpGOkSZXmoahjgmEoWuqY6BjqPkfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>29 26 20 19</s>  11 bytes

```perl6
{$_=($^a+$^b*i)**$^c;.re,.im}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJacn5KqYPu/WiXeVkMlLlFbJS5JK1NTS0slLtlaryhVRy8zt/Z/cWmSQkpmcUFOYqWChkKNs4JmNZeCAlC7Q1FqcWlOiYKVrQLIIIicNVCuGKjSWc8ns7hErwBol46CUkyJrZ2Ckg5My6HdekX5pXkpaGoQCsBiXLVcMHtNdYx0jKzhXEMdE2SurqmOgY6h9X8A)

```perl6
{(($^a+$^b*i)**$^c).reals}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJacn5KqYPu/WkNDJS5RWyUuSStTU0tLJS5ZU68oNTGnuPZ/cWmSQkpmcUFOYqWChkKNs4JmNZeCAlCvQ1FqcWlOiYKVrQLIFIicNVCuGKjSWc8ns7hErwBokY6CUkyJrZ2Ckg5My6HdekX5pXkpaGoQCsBiXLVcMHtNdYx0jKzhXEMdE2SurqmOgY6h9X8A)

```perl6
((*+* *i)** *).reals
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJacn5KqYPtfQ0NLW0tBK1NTC0hq6hWlJuYU/7fmKi5NUkjJLC7ISaxU0FCocVbQrOZSUADqcyhKLS7NKVGwslUAmQCRswbKFQNVOuv5ZBaX6BUALdFRUIopsbVTUNKBaTm0W68ovzQvBU0NQgFYjKuWC2avqY6RjpE1nGuoY4LM1TXVMdAxtP4PAA)

```perl6
((*+* *i)***).reals
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJacn5KqYPtfQ0NLW0tBK1NTS0tLU68oNTGn@L81V3FpkkJKZnFBTmKlgoZCjbOCZjWXggJQm0NRanFpTomCla0CyACInDVQrhio0lnPJ7O4RK8AaIeOglJMia2dgpIOTMuh3XpF@aV5KWhqEArAYly1XDB7TXWMdIys4VxDHRNkrq6pjoGOofV/AA)

With the change of output restrictions it can be further reduced:

```perl6
(*+* *i)***
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJacn5KqYPtfQ0tbS0ErU1NLS@u/NVdxaZJCSmZxQU5ipYKGQo2zgmY1l4ICUHlMUWpxaU6Jgq0CSB9EyhooVQxU6Kznk1lcolcANFpHQSmmxNZOQUlHAaJBryg1Maf40G69ovzSvBQ0hQhVICGuWi6Y1aY6RjpG1nCuoY4JMlfXVMdAx9D6PwA)

The `***` part is parsed as `** *` because the `**` infix operator is longer than the `*` infix operator.

### Expanded:

```perl6
#     __________________ 1st parameter
#    /   _______________ 2nd parameter
#   /   /         ______ 3rd parameter
#  /   /         /
# V   V         V
( * + * * i) ** *
#       ^    ^^
#        \     \________ exponentiation
#         \_____________ multiplication
```

Comment: You can now do `(*+* *i)***`.

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 38 bytes

**Code**

```
c:new dup >r ( r@ c:* ) rot n:1- times
```

**SED** (Stack Effect Diagram) is: `c a b  -- (a + bi) ^ c`

*Warning*: `a + bi` is left on **r-stack**, but this doesn't affect subsequent computations.

**Ungolfed version with comments**

```
needs math/complex

: f \ c a b  -- (a + bi) ^ c
    c:new                      \ create a complex number from a and b
    dup                        \ duplicate a + bi
    >r                         \ store a + bi on r-stack
    ( r@ c:* ) rot n:1- times  \ raise ( a + bi ) to c
;
```

**Example and usage**

```
: app:main
    \ rdrop is not strictly required
    2 5 2 f . cr rdrop
    2 1 4 f . cr rdrop 
    1 -5 0 f . cr rdrop 
    bye
;
```

**Output of the previous code**

```
c:1:data:{"real":21,"imag":20}
c:1:data:{"real":-15,"imag":8}
c:2:data:{"real":-5,"imag":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 25 bytes

simplest - since outputting complex is allowed.

```r
function(a,b,c)(a+b*1i)^c
```

Comment: you can simplify your code by just taking a complex number `z` as input - then function body is simply `z^c`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 9 bytes

Returns an anonymous function that takes a complex number and integer and returns a complex number.

```ruby
proc &:**
```

This is equivalent to `->x,y{x**y}` (11 bytes).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhYrC4rykxXUrLS0IPyb6gUKbtGm2kaZOgpGsVwgjqG2CYKja6ptAOQZxkKUL1gAoQE)